# How to wait till the TFS Build Queued is completed in Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild, build-definition

One of our requirements is to wait till the TFS build which is queued is completed and then we need to perform next task, I have written the below code to achieve this but this isn't giving me the desired results.

```
function Wait-QueuedBuild ()
{
     $serverName="http://tfs001:8080/tfs/Collection"

     $tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($serverName)

     $buildserver = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])

     $build = $buildServer.QueueBuild($buildServer.GetBuildDefinition("CollectionUtility\BUILD_FULL",$_.Name))

     do
     {   
         sleep 1        
     }
     while (!(build.Status -eq 'InProgress'))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep querying the build status in the loop just as Andrey mentioned. The code should like:

```
do {
    sleep 1;
    $queryoption = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.QueryOptions]::All;
    $build = $buildserver.GetQueuedBuild($build.Id,$queryoption);
}
while ($build.Status -eq 'InProgress')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you should actually be in the while loop while the build is in progress:

```
while (build.Status -eq 'InProgress')
```

Also, I think you should query build for updates with [GetBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc340265(v=vs.120).aspx) method